# Multiple Memcache Instances Keeping Pace with each other?

Tags: memcached

I am going to have multiple Instances of Memcache Up and running  for my Application .

(Means Memcache-1 running on Server-A and Memcache-2 running on Server-B .

Is it possible that these  Multiple Instances of the Memcache's servers running in different servers ,   are in sync with each other ??

**Means if Memcache-1 running in server-A has deleted a key , i need to have Memcache-2 running in server-B also need to  delete that  key**

Anyone with experience on this care to share?

Answer (score 1):

Your memcached client should hash each key to a particular server (this should be done under the hood by the client) so there will always be only one key in you memcached cluster. With that said memcached servers do not know that any other memcached servers exist.